# Is there any way to store "Authentication Token" to "Trigger builds remotely" directly in the Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to store "Authentication Token" to "Trigger builds remotely" directly in the Jenkins pipeline.

[Jenkins Parameter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrFYz.png)

Something like:

```
    triggers {
         buildTrigger(token: 'sometoken')
    }
```

Is there any way to do that in the pipeline? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried storing the token as a credential? https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials

Comment: Have a look at the Webhook step plugin. It might help you, but you would need the pipeline to get running on a schedule. Then wait for a webhook created by the pipeline to be called back with a defined token and trigger another job or some such https://github.com/jenkinsci/webhook-step-plugin